# Expectation of the Log. of the Survival Function

Tags: probability, distributions, integral

I am doing some computations for a project and at some point the following expectation shows up

$$ E_{x}[\log(1-F(x))] = \int \log(1-F(x)) f(x)dx  $$

i.e the expectation of the natural logarithm of survivor function (or the ccdf). This has the flavor of an entropy or something like that. I was wondering if somebody could recognize this object and whether you can think of some sort of simplification.

Comment: For continuous distributions I recognize this object as $-1$ ;-).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to spell out @whubers comment:

Assume a continuous distribution, then
$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}}
   \E_X \log\left\{ 1-F(X) \right\} = \int \log\left\{ 1-F(x) \right\} f(x)\; dx =\\
\qquad\qquad \text{use substitution $1-F(x) = u$, with $-f(x)\; dx = du$} \\
=-\int_1^0 \log(u)\; du = \int_0^1 \log(u)\; du = -1
$$ the last equality by partial integration.